# My fa fa-bars is not showing - Responsive Top Navigation

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design, navbar

So I'm switching up my gears a bit here. I created a **responsive nav bar** for my menu, but unfortunately it is not showing the title in the menu bar when it is in mobile form. For my nav bar update, I copied and pasted the codes from W3schools and then modify it a little. I plan to change the color later.

Right now, the only problem I have is that the **fa fa-bars** is not showing when I go into responsive mode. **Why is that?** Here is where I got the responsive nav bar from. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp.

Tell me what am I missing. Thanks. *You can run the code snippet below to see what I'm talking about.*

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Homepage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- The navigation menu -->

  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="about.html">About Me</a>
    <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

***FOR REPLY***

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}


/* This is the part that messed up my styling for my home page which 
    which I previously was pleased with before. */

.summary {
  min-height: 75vh;
  max-width: 2000px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.profilePicture {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.profileSummary {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Homepage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="about.html">About Me</a>
    <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>



  <span>
    <div class="summary">
      <div class="profilePicture">
        <img src="https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.464384650.8618/flat,550x550,075,f.jpg" style="width: 170px; height: 170px; border-radius:50%;">
      </div>
      <div class="profileSummary">
        Attentive alas because yikes due shameful ouch much kookaburra cantankerously up unbridled far vulnerably climbed aristocratically hired brusque fox said the therefore terrier scallop innocent on goodness mongoose woolly showed insistently
        and.
      </div>
    </div>
  </span>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`. If you're using font-awesome don't forget to use the related css.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Homepage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- The navigation menu -->

  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="about.html">About Me</a>
    <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey thanks that seems to worked! Now I got another problem. Please check out my updated codes underneath For Reply noted in bold. It seems to screwed up my profile pic when I am in responsive now.

Comment: and run the snippet and few it in full screen, go F12 and into responsive mode and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Azazel What do you mean by screwed up? Can you add a mockup of what you expect it to be? The span seems as it's supposed to do.

Comment: Here is what it looks like when it is in desktop mode. https://i.imgur.com/lrEeuFB.jpg And here is what it looks when I go into iPhone mode and activate the top nav bar https://i.imgur.com/IiVRBFa.jpg

Comment: Yeah, I've tried on multiple [option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tg733.png) but it's all good in my Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit) browser. [Expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZvPj.png)

Comment: Here it is when it is not tapped, https://i.imgur.com/72RfCWS.jpg, and here it is when it is tapped on my screen. https://i.imgur.com/NHkeGpH.jpg. Something must be wrong on my end. The <span> part where I want everything to be pushed down when the nav menu opens as it worked for me before.

Comment: It seems to look okay for the most part, but when you tap on the nav bar as the menu drops down (or opens), it should either go behind the menu or below the menu.

Comment: You can try adding a `div` before span. Also, can you try making a snippet [here](https://jsfiddle.net/)? And see if it's still occurred?

Comment: Here try and copy and paste this into one of your text editors and open it up in chrome and do the same F12 method. https://jsfiddle.net/dcannon96/t37rqgch/1/. I'll try the div and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Include

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">`

in your before `</head>`

Answer (score -1):

if everything is fine, then u must be having a some internet problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).